# base_convert crashing server?

Tags: php

I have a webapp where I use `base_convert($database_id, 36)` to convert the id to base 36 for the URL. My site stayed up and saw some good traffic early on and was extremely responsive and stable.

Now, after a few months I have something like 130k records and my server is crashing from much less traffic than it saw early on at it's release.

I saw in the php manual that base_convert may lose accuracy with large numbers, so I'm wondering if this could possibly be bugging out my server and crashing it?

How do I do that base conversion without using base_convert to test this out?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"?  What exactly happens?  Is it an apache problem? A database problem?

Comment: @Rapture - When you say the server is crashing, could you elaborate? How do you know it's crashing. What errors do you see?

Comment: I would have to find out more from my hosting company - we've tried multiple database servers and I've since moved to a vps. They have told me that the site was pushing 16 cores to 100% and locking the server up on my shared plan. And it continues to overload the 4 cores i have on the VPS. I'm just confused, because I havent' changed anything in the code, so I started thinking that the only thing that has changed is the db growth - and then I saw that notice about base_convert on php manual

Comment: That's not a crash. Maybe you introduced an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps - I'm not sure why it would rear it's ugly head after a few months on the same code. Thanks for the thoughts guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments - this indeed was NOT my problem. I had inadvertently left the database set in a debug mode on the production server which was obviously creating a lot of overhead. Thanks for the answers, helped me know I should be looking somewhere else!